# Apache Tomcat Servlet threads not finishing

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, servlets, lifecycle

I've written a servlet deployed in tomcat.

```
public class myServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public int NumberOfThreads = 0;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    System.out.println(NumberOfThreads);
    NumberOfThreads++;
    ....
    ..a lot of code..
    ....
    NumberOfThreads--;
    }
}
```

Now when I get too many requests the NumberOfThreads keeps rising and never goes down again. My problem is that there is a few tasks that have to be performed by each request before leaving.

I just don't understand why this happens. Is it that some of the threads get lost on the way? I really need each request to say properly goodbye.

Thanks

Comment: It's hard to say whats wrong with that code if you can't see it ;-) Did you try an IDE to see what's happening with the threads? Try to log the life-cycle of the threads to see what happens.

Comment: This code is not thread safe. So it will be hard to predict whats going on by just looking at the counter. Webapplications generally has worker threads to serve requests monitor them to see exactly whats happening

Comment: Sorry code in between is a few thousand lines. When I see the logs there is nothing that caught my eye. I'll try to get more detailed logs though. So theoretically each request will always run through the entire lifecycle? Even when user cancelled the request?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong.

```
System.out.println(ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean().getThreadCount());
```

Alternatively, just use JMX/JConsole.

Comment: The thread count can be totally discoupled from this application specific code being executed. You'd basically get a count of total threads in the application, not of the servlet executions. E.g. the count through JMX will be limited with the max number of request handler threads (plus others that it might count), while OP might also run into unlimited counts up.

Answer (score 1):

As you're speaking about this taking a long time and requests are being cancelled (in your comment): Yes, the whole `doGet` will be executed, even when the user cancelled the request: Request cancelling is only on HTTP level. However, when the request is cancelled, the HTTP connection might be closed, resulting in exceptions when you actually want to write to the response's output stream.

Combining the other answers already given:

- You'll need to synchronize your modifications of the counter (see didxga's answer)
- there's probably a better way to solve your problem (as Ravi Thapliyal states)
- use try{ ... } finally { ... } to ensure you actually decrease the counter
- make your code more maintainable by moving it out of the servlet into a proper, non-UI, class

Pseudo code:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        synchronized(this){NumberOfThreads++;}
        doSomething();
    } finally {
        synchronized(this){NumberOfThreads--;}
    }
}
```

Also, be aware that long-running execution in the actual http connector thread blocks all subsequent http requests - it might be a good idea to trigger background processing and just query that background process in later HTTP requests. That way you can also queue multiple invocations and not start a huge number of background threads at the same time. Keep in mind, there's a limited number of HTTP request handlers.

I'm assuming the try/finally will be your main problem (or an endless loop in your code) - synchronizing will solve rare race conditions, especially as you're speaking of *a lot* of code executed in this servlet.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I implemented a kind of cashing system. So each thread needs to unlock it's data after completition. With "try finally" I can do that. Simple but I simply did not think about it. Thanks a lot

Comment: well, "try/finally" will not lock anything, and you should rather protect your business code on the business layer, not in the servlet. Still, good that the original problem has been solved

Comment: no its not locking. but makes sure things get unlocked. thats important

Comment: Or one might use AtomicInteger, so synchronization is not neccessary.

Answer (score 0):

You need to synchronize modification to `NumberOfThreads` 
    `public class myServlet extends HttpServlet {
        public int NumberOfThreads = 0;`

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    System.out.println(NumberOfThreads);
    synchronized(this){NumberOfThreads++;}
    ....
    ..a lot of code..
    ....
    synchronized(this){NumberOfThreads--;}
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

The different servlet threads are caching `NumberOfThreads`. You have to mark it as `volatile`.

```
public volatile int NumberOfThreads = 0;
```

But, I have a feeling that there are better ways of doing what you probably want to achieve with this code.

Comment: Using `volatile` in this case wouldn't help because `++` and `--` operations are not atomic ones. But I agree with that there should be much more better solution.

Comment: @IlliaShestakov Yeah, I agree. @All, given a similar situation what should we choose and why? Synchronized blocks or going volatile with `AtomicInteger`?

Comment: I think in this case it is a matter of taste whether you use synchronization or a final AtomicInteger (volatile is not necessary here, since the reference doesn't change).

Comment: @hstoerr Yes, final AtomicInteger should suffice.